# Error:(30, 17) error: code too large solutions?

Tags: java, android, listview, search, large-data

I am making a simple database of medical components. I made a simple `ListView` in android studio that contains names of drugs approximately 9000 names. Names are located in an array(`string[]`) so I can search inside them but when I compile it, it says:

```
Error:(30, 17) error: code too large    
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Read the list from an external source instead of coding it in your java files?

Comment: put code how you tried to do that so that its easy to track down the exact problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - don't put large amounts of data in source code, basically. Just include a text file with all the names, and load that at execution time instead. (In normal Java I'd use `Class.getResourceAsStream`; in Android you should probably be using the [Android resource mechanisms](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html), and you should consider localization too.)

That will *also* make it a lot easier to read and edit the data.

Comment: I think class resources work in Android but the place you usually find them is the `src/main/res/raw/` directory in the project: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html - though drug names are maybe better off in the localizable strings department.

Comment: @zapl: Will add both aspects into the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet You should write an email to StackOverflow for acquiring more space in flair since your badges are not properly visible (sorry for off-field talk, great job by the way).